# Forward/Backward button : Go to next/previous Queue in Text To Speech

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm facing a problem where I need to go to the next or previous Text To Speech queue after adding them using QUEUE_ADD. I've been looking for solution for a while and it seems I didn't found anything about this

I have an array of String and I add it into my Text To Speech queue like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < paraText.length; i++)
    textToSpeech.speak(paraText[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
```

So how do I skip or go back to the previous queue on a button click. A sample code would be great. Thanks.